# Memory Index in Brainfuck Language

Tags: brainfuck, esoteric-languages

I am new to this language.

command `<` is used to decrement the pointer of memory index.

Below code is for adding two single digit number.

According to this program, it first takes input and then stores it at memory[0], as initially memory index is at position 0. It then decrements the memory index, making it now -1 so it should show runtime. Why it is running successfully in IDEone?

Does the memory blocks are in cycle?

```
,                           ;read character and store it in p1
------------------------------------------------   ;return ascii to Dec
<                           ;move pointer to p2 (second byte)
,                           ;read character and store it in p2
------------------------------------------------ ;return ascii to Dec
[                           ; enter loop
-                           ; decrement p2
>                           ; move to p1
+                           ; increment p1
<                           ; move to p2
]                           ; we exit the loop when the last cell is empty
>                           ;go back to p1
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     ;return Dec to ascii
.                           ;print p1
```

Comment: I'm afraid it really isn't clear what you are asking by "does the memory blocks are in cycle?".

Comment: sorry for my bad english , does it work like if memory index =0 and we perform index-- then if size of memory is 3000 then value of index become 3000?

Answer (score 2):

That code clearly has a bug all < should be > and vice versa.

What happens if you try decrementing the pointer past 0 is not defined. Some interpreters crash, some wrap around.

It's best to always assume the interpreter will crash. There is a simple reason for this. Some implementations do not bound the tape to 30000 cells and will keep adding memory as soon as it it requested. Therefore there is no "end" to the tape, so going down from 0 cannot wrap around to the end (because there isn't one)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the interpreter. The original language consists of an array of 30,000 memory cells. Many choose to loop around to the last cell if decrementing at cell zero to avoid throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer to your question basis fully on theory.

First of all, you should know, that [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is designed to be [turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Turing completness of brainfuck assumes that language by itself *can be used to simulate any single-taped [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)*

[Definition of turng machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) assumes *infinite tape*.

Infinite memory is impossible to get. In order to pretend that the tape is infinite you should use as much memory as possible.

If your memory is full, you should throw an exception, because once memory is finite, brainfuck makes no sense at all.